# Iptables Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

I'm new at `iptables`. I'm trying to whitelist a IP. My server is behind a proxy and I'm getting refused connections since the server is thinking the proxy Ip is attacking it.

I have tried this below

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -1 eth0 -s 111.11.1111.111 -j ACCEPT
```

The IP above is example only.

The OS is Ubuntu 11.10

I was wondering if that's the correct way to add it. I also don't know how to save it. I guess every time you reboot you have to add it. I was wondering what the command was to save it so I don't have to keep adding it.

Comment: After rebooting, what is the output of `iptables -n -L`?  Are the lists empty?  If so, then you shouldn't need to add a rule to accept.    If the list is not empty, then you already have something managing your firewall, figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your iptables command is nearly correct, with a few exceptions:

- The `-I` option means Insert, which requires an additional argument to specify where in the rule list the new rule should appear.  For example `-I INPUT 1`
- I believe you wanted `-i` instead of `-1` to specify and input interface specification.
- (optional) You've allowed all traffic, on any port, from this proxy system.  You probably want to specify a protocol and/or port.  Such as `-p tcp --dport 80`, which means protocol TCP with a destination port (on the local system) of 80.  This would allow HTTP traffic.

That all aside, Ubuntu uses a configuration tool called UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall).  You'll probably want to take a look at [some documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/firewall.html) for how you can add custom iptables rules.  Although, you can use UFW directly to add a simple destination rule like this, with:

```
sudo ufw allow from 111.11.11.111 to any app apache
```

This assumes you're trying to allow access to apache.  For other applications, you could try:

```
sudo ufw app list
```